# Weird question about interval of convergence

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

The question is:

if $$ f(x) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$ determine the interval of convergence for the *power series representation of*

$$\int_0^x f(t) \, dt$$

That integral threw me off.

Comment: Do you know a closed-form expression for the power series?

Comment: The derivative and integral of $f$ have the same radii of convergence. It's one of fact taken for granted in Stewart's Calculus.

Comment: Just integrate term by term.

Comment: @zhw. so you mean $$ \int_0^x (x^n) \, dt $$  ?

Comment: @TheOneWhoCould should be $\int_0^x t^n dt$.

Comment: @John so doing that would give x^n+1/ n+1, and then?

Comment: Then you put all these into the summation sign and you are done!